# Android normalize bitmap

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-bitmap

I am integrating a Tensorflow model in an Android app and I need to preprocess my image before feeding it to my model.

For that I need my image to :

1. crop my image to the right dimensions (no problem with this step) :

   `Bitmap bitmap_cropped = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224,false);`
2. get RGB chanels from 0-255 values to 0-1 range. So basically divide all pixels by 255. I tried the code below but I am not sure this does what I need :

   ```
   bitmap_cropped.getPixels(imageBitmapPixels, 0, bitmap_cropped.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap_cropped.getWidth(), bitmap_cropped.getHeight());
   for (int i = 0 ; i < imageBitmapPixels.length; i++) {
       imageBitmapPixels[i] = imageBitmapPixels[i]/255;
   }
   ```

   But when I display the values of each pixels I get something like that

   ```
   -12898260
   -12963540
   -12963540
   -11254211
   ```

I guess the 3 chanels are mixed so I can't check if got what I wanted.. Is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: That's wrong, obviously. Each pixel has ARGB inside, if you divide its value by 255, it will be... umm... meaningless :)
What format of data do you need as a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can give you some idea of what you need to do

```
val rgbs = Array(bitmap.width * bitmap.height){
    val x = it % bitmap.height
    val y = it / bitmap.height

    val pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y)
    val red = (pixel and 0x00FF0000 shr 16) / 255f
    val green = (pixel and 0x0000FF00 shr 8) / 255f
    val blue = (pixel and 0x000000FF) / 255f

    RGB(red, green, blue)
}

data class RGB(val r: Float, val g: Float, val b: Float)
```

Excuse my kotlin

disclamer 1: this code is not performant

disclamer 2: there is probably a lib which doing pretty much the same but faster

disclamer 3: the code above relies on your bitmap being ARGB_8888 format